# Good non-Henle urtext edition of Bach?

Tags: piano, sheet-music, j-s-bach

I am looking to buy a copy of the English Suites, and need an urtext edition. Normally I'd just go to the music store and buy the book; however, they only have the Henle edition, and being a student, I don't really have to spend $45 on a book. Can you recommend any other good urtext edition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good quality Urtexts tend to be expensive... A quick check suggests that Henle, Vienna and Bärenreiter are all similarly priced while Peters is a little cheaper.

The Bach-Gesellschaft Ausgabe is an old Urtext whose quality, they say, varies a lot. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bach_Gesellschaft#Quality_of_the_edition) the parts edited by W. Rust should be of good quality and it just happens that the suites are edited by him (althought there seems to be a corrected version available, too). You can get this (and the corrected version) for free on [IMSLP](http://imslp.org/wiki/6_English_Suites,_BWV_806-811_%28Bach,_Johann_Sebastian%29). There is also a Dover book available which is quite cheap and contains a lot more (but at least my copy is impossible to keep open).

Comment: Yes I have a similar problem with Dover books... When laying them flat they work great, but as soon as you put them at an angle they refuse to stay open until they have a good crease. I'll take a look at the Ausgabe, as long as I can get a preview of how the inside looks.

Comment: Truth. Those Dover books are a great deal, and usually great quality scores, but they're practically worthless without something to hold them open.

Comment: I had the spines shorn from mine and got them spiral-bound, at an office supply store that also does printing.  A 2 mm plastic spiral through holes spaced about 5 mm apart.  Works great, but does occasionally dribble chaff.

Answer (score 1):

I've found new and used books at Amazon US (if that's your location) for ~$10 (Peters, Henle) if you go with half the suites (no. 1-3 *or* 4-6).

Searching for "Englische Suiten" appears to result in more hits...

Answer (score 0):

I found an Urtext edition by an Italian publisher, also available at Amazon: [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/887207407X). I can't comment on the publisher, since I never heard or seen something from it before.

Comment: Not much of a recommendation then, eh?

Answer (score 0):

ABRSM (Associated Board of Royal Schools of Music) editions are generally reliable to work from, and somewhat less costly.